# How to bind combobox with the values extracted with regex?

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, xaml, combobox

Hello everyone,
               i have a problem that i want to bind my WPF combobox with the values which i extracted using regex .Here's my code:

```
string pattern = "/^dhcp pool.*/g";
Console.WriteLine(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(_str, pattern);

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++dhcp pool is ++++++++++++++" + match.Groups[1].Value);
    DHCPoolName = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

DHCPPoolName is the name of the property which i am binding as a ItemSorurce for my combobox.

XAML code:

```
<ComboBox
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="0,4"
    ItemsSource="{Binding DHCPoolName}">              
</ComboBox>
```

DHCPPoolName Property:

```
 public string DHCPoolName
        {

            // Retreive value from Configuration Library
            get
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("get WpaWpa2RadiusKey");
                return this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryDhcpPoolName;
            }

            // Set value in Configuration Library
            set
            {
                if (!String.Equals(this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryDhcpPoolName, value))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("set WpaWpa2RadiusKey");
                    this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryDhcpPoolName = value;

                    // ValidateWLAN1RadiusKey(value);

                    this.OnPropertyChanged("DHCPoolName");
                }
            }
        }
```

I did'nt succeed in binding my combobox with the values i extracted can anyone tell me where i am doing mistake?

Comment: Please define DHCPPoolName property. what type of collection?

Comment: its a string,i have also edit it in the above code

Comment: You can define a Collection of string property as simple binding to string property won`t help!!

Comment: I changed ItemsSource="{Binding DHCPoolName}" to ItemsSource="{Binding}" but it is not showing me anything in the combobox

Answer (score 0):

You can define a string Collection

```
private ObservableCollection<string> dhcppoolname;
 public ObservableCollection<string> DHCPoolName
    {
        get
        {
            if(dhcppoolname == null)
            {
                dhcppoolname = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            }
            return dhcppoolname;
        }
        set
        {
            dhcppoolname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DHCPoolName");
        }
    }
```

In the foreach loop

```
    foreach(Match match in matches)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++dhcp pool is ++++++++++++++" + match.Groups[1].Value);
      DHCPoolName.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
   }
```

Comment: Please also post the code on how you are setting up the DataContext.

Comment: Still the combobox is empty ,,i think it is not entering in the foreach loop ,,i dont know why ??

Comment: @CodeTheft please check whether DHCPoolName property is getting set. also please post some code on how are you setting the DataContext

Comment: i am getting my datacontext from networking device  for which i am creating this application i run back end command via telnet and then i need to fill my combobox upon the outcome of telnet command.